# Pattern matching in a redis sorted sets and return results in order

Tags: redis, node-redis, sortedset

I have a redis sorted set.

I need to fetch members from the set that match a specific regex pattern IN ORDER.

I was using ZSCAN, but it does not return results in order.
With ZRANGE, I am not able to do regex matching.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Even `ZSCAN` does not support regex, it supports glob-like patterns only.

This is a classic use case for using [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval). In your script you'll be able to either `ZSCAN` and then sort, or `ZRANGE` and then apply the filtering. Happy hacking ;)